# How to get the last value of a result efficiently

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, hive

I am trying to execute a hive query from the java file . I want to get only the last result from the show database query .

Instead of iterating through all the query results to find out the last value, is there any way to directly point the last output.

```
example : show databases ;
Db1 
DB2
DB3

Output should be DB3 

public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ProcessBuilder hiveProcessBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("hive", "-e",
                "show databases");
        Process hiveProcess = hiveProcessBuilder.start();

        OutputRedirector outRedirect = new OutputRedirector(
                hiveProcess.getInputStream(), "HIVE_OUTPUT");
        OutputRedirector outToConsole = new OutputRedirector(
                hiveProcess.getErrorStream(), "HIVE_LOG");

        outRedirect.start();
        outToConsole.start();
    }

    public static class OutputRedirector extends Thread {

        InputStream is;
        String type;

        public OutputRedirector(InputStream is, String type) {
            this.is = is;
            this.type = type;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String line = null;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String result = line;
                    System.out.println(type + "> " + result);
                }
            } catch (IOException ioE) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you will usually parse along the input stream and wait for your desired content.

Still, as you are trying to capture the output of a command line program,  you won't know when it will finish. Because of that, I wouldn't use a BufferedReader, but to read the characters periodically with the InputStreamReader itself. You could do that by reading a few characters like every second and remember the last line break to know your complete line.

Finally you should check for an indicator that shows you reached the end of your result set that has been put out.

Additionally, this thread will run forever, so if you do not need it anymore, but you don't want to shutdown your parent process (e.g. the application itself), you will have to use an interrupt to shutdown the process properly, you can check here how to do it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(is);
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            String currentLastLine = null;

            while (true) {
                int nextchar = in.read();
                //nextchar == -1 -> we are at the end of the stream
                if (nextchar == -1) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } else {
                    buffer.append(nextchar);
                }

                //new line here
                if (nextchar == 10) {
                    // check for end of result indicator
                    String newLastLine = buffer.toString();
                    // this could be something like .contains('hive >') as well
                    // END_OF_RESULT_SET must be defined according to your output
                    if (newLastLine.matches(END_OF_RESULT_SET)) {
                        // here currentLastLine is your desired line,
                        // so do something with it
                        System.out.println("Result: "+currentLastLine);
                    }

                    currentLastLine = newLastLine;
                    buffer = new StringBuilder();
                }

            }
        } catch (IOException ioE) {
          ...
        } catch (...) {
          ...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, only streams are supported by the Process class, see
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

The idea of streams IS the sequential access, so unless your process doesn't have some Java interface API (like OJDBC for accessing Oracle databases), you can only iterate through your stream until you got to the last line, I'm sorry.

Comment: Is there any other way I can execute hive query then.   Apart from using the hive connection

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea.